# Utilise AJAX & javascript to create a toast with Djangos messaging framework

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax

I have followed a tutorial to utilise AJAX to validate an input field before attempting to submit. I have it working on my django built site; however, I have been using toasts to alert the user to other actions and did not want to get way from this.

```
$("#id_hub_name").focusout(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the hubname
    var hub_name = $(this).val();
    // GET AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{% url 'validate_hubname' %}",
        data: {"hub_name": hub_name},
        success: function (response) {
            // if not valid user, alert the user
            if(!response["valid"]){
                alert("You cannot create a hub with same hub name");
                var hubName = $("#id_hub_name");
                hubName.val("")
                hubName.focus()
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
})
```

This is my current JS, I want to change the alert function to use toasts instead.

In my base.html I use the following to listen for toasts and create them.

```
{% if messages %}
    <div class="message-container">
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% with message.level as level %}
                {% if level == 40 %}
                    {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_error.html' %}
                {% elif level == 30 %}
                    {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_warning.html' %}
                {% elif level == 25 %}
                    {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_success.html' %}
                {% else %}
                    {% include 'includes/toasts/toast_info.html' %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the html element for the toast.

First of all, loose the `{% if messages %}`, make sure `<div class="message-container">` is always present in your template. If there are no messages, it will just be an empty `div`.You also need to add the templates for the toasts in js as well, so that you can just append the toasts from JS.

Now you can just append the template for the toast after your ajax response.

something like:

```
function show_alert_from_js(alert_type, text) {
        msg = `<<your template here>>${text}`;  // to render the text message to show.
        msg_html = $.parseHTML(msg);
        $('.message-container').append(msg_html);
}

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        ...
        success: function (response) {
            if(!response["valid"]){
                show_alert_from_js("error", "You cannot create a hub with same hub name")
            ...

})
```

Comment: Hi Aman,

Thats great, it works!! Thank you.

A follow up question, how can I style the toasts? I have been using a standard bootstrap toast to display alerts. However, if I try to embed that within the html it shows up on page rendering and doesnt show up with an alert.

Comment: you can use `$('#element').toast('show')` on the toast element to make it visible any time. [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/#methods)